# Does dynamic memory get extended automatically in C?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was writing a simple program to see how dynamic memory allocations in C works.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                      
#include <stdlib.h>     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
int main() {                                                                                                                    
    char* c = (char* ) malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);                                                                            
    int* a = (int* ) malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);                                                                               
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)                                                                                                  
        *(a+i) = i;                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    c = "Hello World";                                                                                                      
    printf("%c\n", *(c+4));                                                                                                   
    printf("%d\n", *(a+4));                                                                                                   
    return 0;                                                                                                       
}
```

The output I get is

```
o

4
```

I've allocated enough memory to save a single character and an integer. But then, how is a whole string and an array of integers of length 10 getting saved?

Does the memory automatically get extended? Could someone kindly explain how it works?
Thanks.

Comment: You can sometimes access memory out of bounds of the specified allocation, but it is unsafe to do so. If you go too far, you will trigger a segfault.

Comment: Undefined behavior means anything _can_ happen, including your program "working."

Comment: *Undefined behavior*  behaves in undefined ways

Comment: It's undefined behaviour when you access outside the bounds of the memory you requested.  Anything can happen; the program isn't required to crash; it isn't required to produce a right answer; it isn't required to produce a wrong answer; it isn't required to preserve all the files on your disk, but you don't usually lose them because of a mild case of undefined behaviour.  But anything is possible.  Don't bother experimenting with undefined behaviour — what you find today may not apply to other systems, new versions of the system, new versions of the compiler, or new versions of the libraries.

Comment: Also, in `c = "Hello World";` you are not copying a string into the memory you allocated with `malloc` but having `c` point to a string literal. If you wanted to copy into that memory, you'd use `strcpy` or one of its close cousins. As it is, printing `c` is _not_ undefined behavior, but that byte of memory you allocated is a (very minor) memory leak.

Comment: To be more precise: on a typical system, memory is generally allocated by the system in chunks of the page size (usually 4K), and then divvied up by the C library from there.  So, you won’t necessarily trigger a “page fault”, cause the page is allocated to your process, but you may be overwriting other variables (or even variables you have yet to allocate!) which will result in memory corruption.  Because the standard can’t actually tell what will happen on any given system, it just gives the name “undefined behaviour”: anything can happen, and it may happen much later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In accessing the dynamically allocated array `a` out of bounds, you invoke undefined behavior. The program may do *anything*, including "working" the way you expected.

```
    int* a = (int* ) malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);                                                                               
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)                                                                                                  
        *(a+i) = i;
```

I will suggest a different syntax, and that you not cast the result of `malloc`.

```
    int* a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);                                                                               
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)                                                                                                  
        a[i] = i;
```

As for your string:

```
char* c = (char* ) malloc(sizeof(char) * 1);

c = "Hello World";
```

You are allocating one byte of memory and `c` is pointing to it. You then reassign `c` to point to a string literal. As a result, you can print `c` without issue. Since the dynamically allocated memory is no longer pointed to, you cannot `free` it and a very small memory leak is created.

If you wanted to copy `Hello World" into the memory` c` pointed to initially, you'd write:

```
strcpy(c, "Hello World");
```

But this would access out of bounds for `c`, and we'd be back in the territory of undefined behavior.

Please note that strings in C require a null terminating character at the end. A single char's memory cannot store a string as it only has room for the null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment `c = "Hello World"` just causes `c` to point to the string literal and the single character allocated has been leaked.

You've written beyond the allocated size of the array `a` but it's not surprise those addresses are accessible to your program so you don't get a protection/segmentation fault.

Your code then ends before you do anything else with `malloc()` and `free()` so you never trip over what memory corruption your `for`-loop may have introduced.

As comments point out "undefined behaviour" includes your program working as intended.

In my experience overwriting the bounds of dynamically allocated memory often appears to work and then crashes about 3 or more allocations later.

Your program is probably terminating before it trips over the mess you've made of it's memory.

In programming breaking things isn't usually a good way to find out how they work.

Comment: I would suggest that breaking things is a great way to find out how they work, or Stack Overflow wouldn't exist. But break small things and learn from fixing them before you start breaking really big programs.

Comment: @Chris Not in programming. They don't break in consistent or useful ways. If or how they break on one platform tends to mislead about another. For example when I run the program in the OP I get an abnormal program termination. You shouldn't be afraid to break things, but deliberately breaking things (as the OP did) really isn't productive.